# Fraud Detection DataStream API tutorial questions

Tags: apache-flink, data-stream

I am following the tutorial [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/try-flink/datastream_api.html).

**Q1**: Why in the final application do we clear all states and delete timer whenever `flagState = true` regardless of the current transaction amount? I refer to this part of the code:

```
// Check if the flag is set
if (lastTransactionWasSmall != null) {
    if (transaction.getAmount() > LARGE_AMOUNT) {
        //Output an alert downstream
        Alert alert = new Alert();
        alert.setId(transaction.getAccountId());

        collector.collect(alert);
    }
    // Clean up our state [WHY HERE?]
    cleanUp(context);
}
```

If the datastream for a transaction was `0.5, 10, 600`, then `flagState` would be set for `0.5` then cleared for `10`. So for `600`, we skip the code block above and don't check for large amount. But if `0.5` and `600` transactions occurred within a minute, we should have sent an alert but we didn't.

**Q2**: Why do we use processing time to determine whether two transactions are 1 minute apart? The transaction class has a `timeStamp` field so isn't it better to use event time? Since processing time will be affected by the speed of the application, so two transactions with event times within 1 minute of each other could be processed > 1 minute apart due to lag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A1**: The fraud model being used in this example is explained by this figure:

[image]

In your example, the transaction `600` must immediately follow the transaction for `0.5` to be considered fraud. Because of the intervening transaction for `10`, it is not fraud, even if all three transactions occur within a minute. It's just a matter of how the use case was framed.

**A2**: Doing this with event time would be a very valid choice, but would make the example much more complex. Not only would watermarks be required, but we would also have to sort the stream by event time, since a realistic example would have to consider that the events might be out-of-order.

At that point, implementing this with a process function would no longer be the best choice. Using the temporal pattern matching capabilities of either Flink's CEP library or Flink SQL with MATCH_RECOGNIZE would be the way to go.

Comment: A1: Fraud Detector v2 says: "suppose you wanted to set a 1 minute timeout to your fraud detector". The immediately after requirement is for v1.

Comment: V2 is simply adding an additional constraint.

Comment: OH that makes sense! I thought V2 was replacing the V1 requirement. Thanks for your help.